# How can pass array list object from an activity to fragment in android

Tags: android

I am storing some values in array list now i want to pass the same array list object to fragment from an activity. So how can i send the array list object from an activity and receive the same object in fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your activity, It is a code snippet from my working application.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    yourArrayList.add("test");
    yourArrayList.add("test2")
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArrayList("arrayList", yourArrayList);
    yourFragment yourFragment = new yourFragment();
    yourFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, yourFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

In your fragment you can access the value like this

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<String> values = getArguments().getStringArrayList("arrayList");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

pass activity  should follow this  lines

```
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArrayList("valuesArray", namesArray);
    namesFragment myFragment = new namesFragment();
    myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, myFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

get Fragment inside follow this lines

```
 ArrayList<ObjectName> arraylist  = extras.getParcelableArrayList("valuesArray");
```

Comment: Hmmm `ArrayList<ObjectName> arraylist` sure about this line.?  will it work for `T` objects?

Comment: ur model name  ex: ArrayList<MyModel> arraylist

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following the usual way of Fragment-Activity communication. That is:

1) Declare a public interface within your Fragment class.

2) Inside this interface declare a getter method for your list.

3) Make your respective Activity implement this interface.

4) Inside your Fragment, do this:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    YourInterfaceType activity = (YourInterfaceType) context;
    List<> yourList = activity.getMyList();
}
```

**To make it more clear:**

Your activity will be as follows:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements YourInterfaceType{
    @Override
    public void getMyList(){
       return yourList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> just put your array with setargument in Actiivty and get Array
>   getArgument in fragment.

**Activity**

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArrayList("valuesArray", namesArray);
    namesFragment myFragment = new namesFragment();
    myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, myFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**fragment**

```
 ArrayList<Model> values = getArguments().getStringArrayList("valuesArray");
```